# Django distinct() generates query for not one column (as needed)

Tags: sql, django

When I do this queryset:

```
Club.objects.values('district').distinct()
```

I expect to get this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `club_club`.`district` FROM `club_club` ORDER BY `club_club`.`name` ASC
```

But Django generates this query (adds 'name' column):

```
>>> print Club.objects.values('district').distinct().query
SELECT DISTINCT `club_club`.`district`, `club_club`.`name` FROM `club_club` ORDER BY `club_club`.`name` ASC
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query you are expecting is **invalid** `order by column` has to be in `select list` if you are using `distinct keyword`, or else you will get this standard SQL error

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```